# Android - how to select an item in a GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, selection

I have a GridView with ImageView items, and I want to select programmatically an item at some position. I thought it would be easy, but... `setSelection` does nothing, why?

```
public class Test extends Activity {
  public void onCreate (final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    GridView gridView = new GridView (this);
    gridView.setNumColumns (4);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing (16);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing (16);
    setContentView (gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter (new BaseAdapter () {
      public int getCount () {
        return 12;
      }
      public Object getItem (int position) {
        return position;
      }
      public long getItemId (int position) {
        return position;
      }
      public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
          view = new ImageView (Test.this);
          view.setImageResource (R.drawable.image);
        }
        return view;
      }
    });

    gridView.setSelection (3); // ?? does nothing    
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe add gridView.setSelection (3);  after setContentView (gridView);

Comment: @SirukViktor Tried this, but it changes nothing...

Comment: Maybe try defining one of your items in the gridview and then giving that item an onClickListener.? Also is there a reason you're declaring your gridview in your java page as apposed to your xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2008/12/touch-mode.html), you can't select an item in touch mode...
So you have to manage the selection and item highlighting yourself :-/